# accessing data in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, api

I am working with an API and when I run my query I can print out the structure of the array returned using `var_dump`. How do I go about returning just the `primaryAccountName`?

Here is my php source code:

```
// Configuration
$apiKey   = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
// End of configuration

require_once('NutshellApi.php');
$api = new NutshellApi($username, $apiKey);

// My search query
$result = $api->searchLeads(array('string' => "https://app01.nutshell.com/lead/49201", 'limit' => 1));

// var dump data is sampled below
var_dump($result);
```

This is the data that is returned in the browser:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass) #3 (14) { 
            ["stub"] => bool(true) 
            ["id"] => int(188681) 
            ["rev"] => string(2) "29" 
            ["entityType"] => string(5) "Leads" 
            ["name"] => string(12) "Leadâ€“49201" 
            ["description"] => string(2) "RD" 
            ["status"] => int(0) 
            ["completion"] => int(61) 
            ["value"] => object(stdClass) #4 (2) { 
                ["currency"] => string(3) "USD" 
                ["amount"]=> int(150000) 
            } 
            ["primaryAccountName"] => string(11) "XYZ Industries" 
            ["primaryContactName"] => string(11) "John Doe" 
            ["isOverdue"] => bool(false) 
            ["lastContactedDate"] => string(0) "" 
            ["nextStepDueTime"] => string(24) "2014-10-29T15:52:40+0000" 
        } 
}
```

When I tried the suggestion in the comments, `$result[0]["primaryAccountName"]`, I got the error

> `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/location/location/location/file.php on line 12`

Comment: `$var[0]->value->primaryAccountName`, where `$var` is a variable which `var_dump` is shown.

Comment: Or `$var[0]->primaryAccountName` if it looks the way @dotnetom formatted it :))

Comment: @Cheery, I went ahead and made a revision to my post including the php source.  Thanks again in advance!

Comment: post output for `print_r($result);` try accessing data using `$result[0]["primaryAccountName"]`

Comment: @SandipPingle , went ahead and updated my code and included Fatal Error.

Comment: Have you tried using `$result[0]->primaryAccountName`?

Comment: Objects cannot be used as associative arrays, despite the fact that the `var_dump` may lead you to believe so. The code posted in the other comments is a good way to go. You can read about Object Oriented Programming in PHP here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: I got it thank you guys! :) $account_name = $result[0]->primaryAccountName; print_r($account_name);

Answer (score 0):

$result is array of objects.
 so can u try

```
 echo $result[0]->primaryAccountName;
          (or)
 $objResult=$result[0];
 echo $objResult->primaryAccountName;
```